# How to prevent google action from closing the conversation if there is no intent match?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

whenever default fallback intent is triggered 3 times in a row conversation is getting closed with the response, my test app left the conversation. How can i prevent this from happenning and also only exit from the action only when user wants to exit from the action.

Answer (score 0):

The Actions on Google docs mention a `conv.data.fallbackCount` object, which you can read about in the [No-match reprompting](https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/fulfillment#no-match_reprompting) subsection:

```
 app.intent('Default Fallback Intent', (conv) => {

 conv.data.fallbackCount++;

 // Provide two prompts before ending game

 if (conv.data.fallbackCount === 1) {
   conv.contexts.set(DONE_YES_NO_CONTEXT, 5);
   conv.ask('Are you done playing Number Genie?');
 } else {
   conv.close(`Since I'm still having trouble, so I'll stop here. ` +
     `Let’s play again soon.`);
 }

});
```

Although it's arguably better [conversation design](https://developers.google.com/actions/design/) to leave this variable alone -- thereby letting the conversation close when the counter increments to three -- you could try resetting `conv.data.fallbackCount` manually, like:

```
conv.data.fallbackCount = 0;
```

Comment: initially i was using default intent provided by the agent but then i created a weebhook for the fallback intent. After i created a webhook for the fallback intent now app is not exiting from the conversation. 3 repromts is the default behaviour for the fallback intent before the action exits from the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

At least right now with the new Google Action you can just redirect the user to the current scene again on a `NO_MATCH` intent.

Basically in your webhook just set:

```
webhookResponseJson.scene.next.name = webhookRequestJson.scene.name
```